# Esperanto TLD (Top Level Domain)

Tags: technology

Is there any existing [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) for esperanto websites, or any plan for creating one?

Wiki states that `epo` is the ISO code for esperanto language, so it could be used as the de facto TLD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.epo` could work, and there is precedent with other language-specific TLDs such as [.cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cat) (for the Catalan language). It was backed by a non-profit promoting the use of the language, so in theory something like the UEA could suggest and back a .epo TLD.... funds permitting of course.

Answer (score 2):

I remember a discussion about applying for ".eo". But who will pay for that? So no, there is no TLD for Esperanto.

Comment: Concerning .eo, it is not possible because two-letter top-level domains are reserved for country codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain

Comment: Isn't Esperantujo an country? I prefer eo over epo but why not have both? :D

Comment: @johmue , kiom kostus apliki por la .epo TLD?

Comment: Kelkcent mil eŭrojn, laŭ tio, kion mi iam aŭdis.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `.ejo` ? It means "place" (so it remembers site) and it's similar to "eo" which is the language code for esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

Kelkaj personoj uzas `.io` por tio. Kompreneble http://esperant.io estas rimarkinda ekzemplo.

De Abĥazio ĝis Zambio, multe nomoj de ejo finas per *-io*. La [listo de nunaj sendependaj landoj](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listo_de_sendependaj_%C5%9Dtatoj) enhavas 73 nomojn tiel formitaj el 193, do proksime 37,82%.

Tio dirita, ĝi ne estas ajne oficiale rilata al Esperanto.

Comment: Aliaj similaj TLDoj kiuj povas taŭgi: .eco, .limo, .video. Mi rimarkis ke sen.limo jam estas esperanta retejo. Por havi nomon ĉe .eco oni devas pretendi esti ekologia organizaĵo.